# Are there any way to check that master/primary not available in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, replication, pymongo, replicaset

In my app I am trying to graceful handling case when the master is not available for some reason (for example the connection between DC is broken). In this case write operations should be disabled on the frontend and the cache database should be used for some read operations.

I have tried to use `rs.status()` command. It works from `mongo` shell, but it doesn't work from `pymongo` when the master is not available because `replSetGetStatus` command is not in list `rp.secondary_ok_commands`. As result I have got exception:

> AutoReconnect: No replica set primary available for query with ReadPreference PRIMARY.

Of cause I can handle this exception, but it is generated after timeout (in my case 10 seconds). But it is too long in my case. I prefer immediate response, and it is ok for me if sometimes it will be incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We introduced the [alive()](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.html#pymongo.mongo_replica_set_client.MongoReplicaSetClient.alive) method in PyMongo for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you. It is good for me, although it take one seconds when master is not available.

Comment: Good point. It would be better if alive() didn't attempt to actually connect to the primary. I've [filed an issue, PYTHON-615](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-615), to fix alive()'s behavior in the next release of PyMongo.